# Error when Enabling a Contact as a Partner User

Tags: lightning

I'm trying to Enable a Contact as a Partner User but I'm facing an error - `Portal Account Owner Has No Role`.

I have already checked if the User is Active. I have also enabled `Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration, user creation, and login`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of that record go to your user setting and assign role to your user.

you can refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_partner_roles_overview.htm&type=5) for details.

[image]